# Pandas: extend resampling window

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a 'low-frequency' series with data points every 2 hours, which I'd like to upsample to a 1-hour freq.

Is it possible in the code snippet below to have the high-freq signal have 24 rows (instead of 23)? More precisely, I'd like the new index to range from 00:00 to 23:00 with a `NaN` value (instead of stopping at 22:00).

I've played quite a bit with the several options but I still couldn't find out a clean way to do it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

low_f = pd.Series(np.random.randn(12), 
               index=pd.date_range(start='01/01/2017', freq='2H', periods=12),
               name='2H').cumsum()

high_f = low_f.resample('1H', ).mean()

print(high_f.tail(1).index)

#Yields DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-01 22:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='H') 
#I'd like DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-01 23:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='H') 
#(w/ 24 elements)
```

Comment: I'm not sure there is a 'clean' way to do this. The following will get the job done: `high_f[high_f.index[-1] + 1] = np.nan`

Comment: Didn't know about this neat TimeIndex property! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DateTimeIndex.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.shift.html) method to shift the dates by an 1 hour (leading). Take the [`union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.union.html) of it's old index and the newly formed shifted index.

Finally, [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) them according to these set of indices. As there would be no values of the `series` occuring at the last index, they would be filled by `NaN` as per it's default `fill_value` parameter.

```
high_f.reindex(high_f.index.union(high_f.index.shift(1, 'H')))
```

Comment: Thank you. I compared the timings vs. Ted Petrou's answer (`high_f[high_f.index[-1] + 1] = np.nan`) and yours appears to be slightly faster on my typical test cases.